# How to calculate a Cumulative total using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `Tickets` table in My database , each Ticket have a `status_id` (1,2,3)

```
1:  Ticket IN PROGRESS
2:  Ticket Out Of time
3:  Ticket Closed
```

- I want using SQL to calculate the number of tickets for each status .
- Calculate  the cumulative total for each Status in a specific Date, I have already  a column `affectation_Date` that contains the date where the status of ticket has been changed .

Comment: Sample data and desired results, please.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please edit your question to post sample data and expected results too all as _formatted text_ not images.

Comment: Also, do you want one (1) query or two (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *conditional aggregation* as

```
SELECT TicketID,
       AffectationDate,
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) InProgress,
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OuOfTime,
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Closed,
       COUNT(1) Total
FROM Tickets
GROUP BY TicketID,
         AffectationDate
ORDER BY TicketID,
         AffectationDate;
```

Or if you want to `GROUP BY AffectationDate` only

```
SELECT AffectationDate,
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalInProgress,
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalOutOfTime,
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalClosed,
       COUNT(1) TotalStatusThisDate
FROM Tickets
GROUP BY AffectationDate
ORDER BY AffectationDate;
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0d2dc813544412c8e224d6d6a55bdc3f)**

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional counts.

```
SELECT affectation_Date,
COUNT(CASE WHEN status_id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS TotalInProgress,
COUNT(CASE WHEN status_id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS TotalOutOfTime,
COUNT(CASE WHEN status_id = 3 THEN 1 END) AS TotalClosed
FROM Tickets t
GROUP BY affectation_Date
ORDER BY affectation_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `group by` `status` and `count` the number of tickets in each group:

```
select status, count(*) as number
from Tickets
where dt >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00' and dt < '2019-01-02 00:00:00'
group by status
having status >= 1 and status <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use the desired filter condition for the date criteria

```
SELECT COUNT(1), STATUS 
FROM tickets
WHERE affectation_Date >= 'someDate'
group by status
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This adds the *Cumulative Sum* to the existing answers:

```
SELECT AffectationDate,
       Sum(CASE WHEN StatusID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalInProgress,
       Sum(CASE WHEN StatusID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalOutOfTime,
       Sum(CASE WHEN StatusID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalClosed,
       Count(*) as TotalStatusThisDate,
       Sum(Sum(CASE WHEN StatusID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) Over (ORDER BY AffectationDate) AS cumTotalInProgress,
       Sum(Sum(CASE WHEN StatusID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) Over (ORDER BY AffectationDate) AS cumTotalOutOfTime,
       Sum(Sum(CASE WHEN StatusID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) Over (ORDER BY AffectationDate) AS cumTotalClosed,
       Sum(Count(*)) Over (ORDER BY AffectationDate) AS cumTotalStatusThisDate
FROM Tickets
GROUP BY AffectationDate
ORDER BY AffectationDate;
```